# Cordova Network and Camera API returns undefined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Building my first Cordova 4.0 app, and I would really need some help since I'm gonna show a demo of this app tmrw...

When I try to access the Network info API and the Camera API (`navigator.connection` and `navigator.camera` respectively) they always return undefined.

I have these right in my Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And here are the installed plugins:

```
org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.3 "Camera"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.11 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.12 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.13 "Network Information"
```

I have also copied the `cordova.js` file from the platform-folder and added the `<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></SCRIPT>` tag to my index.html. Also here's an example of my code where I try to access the camera API:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    $(document).on('click', '.camera', function(){

        if (!navigator.camera) {
            alert("Camera API not supported", "Error");
            return;
        }
        var options =   {   quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: 1,      // 0:Photo Library, 1=Camera, 2=Saved Album
            encodingType: 0     // 0=JPG 1=PNG
        };
        navigator.camera.getPicture( function(imgData) { return imgData; }, function() { alert('Error');}, options);

    });
}
```

When I run this I always get the "Camera API not supported" alert, meaning it's undefined.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you added the `script` tag containing `cordova.js` to your html file? Also you need to wait for the `deviceready` event to fire, before checking the cordova APIs. You need to show your HTML file and your code so that we can understand where the issue is.

Comment: @frank Yes, the cordova.js is added. I have updated my post with some code from my index.html file. As you can see it waits for the deviceready to fire, but it is still undefined.

Comment: @frank I got my `cordova.js` file by copying it from the `project_folder/platform/android/platform_www` folder. Is that the correct file?

Comment: you need to add the tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` to your `index.html` file. where are you copying the `cordova.js `file to?

Comment: Yes, I have added that to my JS-folder. `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>`

Comment: I solved it thank god, and you :) when I changed it to <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> and let cordova add the file automatically it worked.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to this question was that Cordova automatically includes the `cordova.js` file in the projects www on build. So all I had to do was include the `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`tag.

That is, my copying the `cordova.js` file and including it into my JS-folder was unnecessary. Hope this might help somebody.